# Best Practice for using Form Data in a http request

Tags: javascript, forms, servlets

We have a previous implementation whereby we send one key value pair in the form data to the server
ie. `message=something_blah`

Is there any point in actually having this in form data? Should form data only be used if we are building an object or array of object? 
If we only have one key value pair would it not be better to insert it as part of the query request parameter?

Comment: Form data parameters and query parameters, from the servlet point of view, are the same.

Comment: Should form data be an object? i.e {message:something_blah} or does it not matter?

Comment: What method are you using: POST or GET?

Comment: I'm using POST to send the HTTP request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form parameters and query parameters are accessed, more or less, from the same place from within a servlet.

For example, in `doGet()` (`doPost()` would've gone the same way, so would all the other http methods)

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String message = request.getParameter("message"); // would return something_blah or null if no parameter 
    ...
}
```

To answer your question in the OP comments, parameters coming from `request.getParameter()` are Strings. You can then convert them to other types (parse to numerical value) or use them to initialize Class instances. Their use is up to you.

This parameter could have come from

```
<form method="get">
    <input name="message" type="text" value="something_blah"/>
</form>
```

or from the url

```
http://www.yourdns.com/myapp?message=something_blah
```

To answer *Should form data only be used if we are building an object or array of object?*, some frameworks like Spring use parameters coming from html forms (and query string) to automatically instantiate objects for you using reflection and some naming conventions. This is not necessary, it's just useful. So review your requirements and see if you need it.